# How to get the values in url using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get value from url using jquery I am trying to get multiple values in jQuery

this is my url

```
https://dev.example.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessage&=deborah-reynolds&Deborah%20Reynolds

var url      =window.location.href; 
var str = decodeURIComponent(url.split('=').pop());
```

I am getting these values

**deborah-reynolds&Deborah Reynolds**

now i want to further breakdown like this

**deborah-reynolds**

**Deborah Reynolds**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to split one more time with `&` separator.

```js
var url = 'https://dev.example.com/front-end-pm/?fepaction=newmessage&=deborah-reynolds&Deborah%20Reynolds'

var str = decodeURIComponent(url.split('=').pop()).split('&');
// here-------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^--

console.log(str[0])
console.log(str[1])
```